# MySql Convert to UTC

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert CET date to UTC Format in MySql. Whats wrong with this?

```
SELECT 
CONVERT_TZ('2018-01-26T06:15:00+01:00', @@session.time_zone, '+00:00');
```

Expected:
2018-01-26T05:15:00Z

Actual:
2018-01-26T06:15:00Z

I guess it is not taking the `+01:00` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's [date format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) doesn't have a timezone. It is interpreting your `'2018-01-26T06:15:00+01:00'` as `'2018-01-26 06:15:00'`.

The 1-st parameter is the time, the 2-nd parameter is the time zone for the 1-st and the 3-rd is the result time zone.

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT_TZ('2018-01-26T06:15:00', '+01:00', '+00:00');
```